# sql sum distinct with same values on cells

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I have this 2 tables

**[Table1]**

```
Name     |    cr      |   value   |   obs 
==============================================
John          1           300       
John          10          550
John          12          34       
John          401         190        
John          10          300
```

**[Table2]**

```
Name     |    cr      |   value   |   obs 
==============================================
John          500         2         obs1
John          500         2         value2
John          500         170
```

And i need to have this

```
name  |  cr 1   |  cr 10    |   cr 12   |  cd 500  |  cr 401  | total
John     300        850          34          174        190     1548
```

I'm trying to use this query but not getting the right result

```
select 
nome,
isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 1 then value end)),0) as 'cr 1',
isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 10 then value end)),0) as 'cr 10',
isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 12 then value end)),0) as 'cr 12',
isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 500 then value end)),0) as 'cr 500',
isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 401 then value end)),0) as 'cr 401',
(   isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 1 then value end)),0) +
    isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 10 then value end)),0) +
    isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 12 then value end)),0) +
    isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 500 then value end)),0) +
    isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 401 then value end)),0)
) AS Total

from table1 left join table2 on table1.name = table2.name

group by name
```

The problem is that with this query I do not have the right result on the 'cr 500'

Any help will be welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server` then it would better to use `pivot` with dynamic headers, in this way you don't need to use `CASE` for each values.

Comment: Why do you have distinct before each sum? Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL`

```
select t.*, cr1 + cr10 + cr12 + cr500 + cr401 as total
from
(
    select 
        name,
        isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 1 then value end)),0) as cr1,
        isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 10 then value end)),0) as cr10,
        isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 12 then value end)),0) as cr12,
        isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 500 then value end)),0) as cr500,
        isnull(sum(distinct(case when cr = 401 then value end)),0) as cr401
    from (
      select * from table1 
      union all
      select * from table2
    ) t
    group by name
) t
```

Comment: Yes, the union all solve my problem, thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @BrunoAlves just make sure you really want that distinct there. it may eliminate certain values from the result (if they are the same).

Comment: Yes I remove the distinct ;)

Answer (score 0):

You do want a `union all`, but I think this is the version of the query you want:

```
select name,
       sum(case when cr = 1 then value else 0 end) as cr1,
       sum(case when cr = 10 then value else 0 end) as cr10,
       sum(case when cr = 12 then value else 0 end) as cr12,
       sum(case when cr = 500 then value else 0 end) as cr500,
       sum(case when cr = 401 then value else 0 end) as cr401,
       sum(case when cr in (1, 10, 12, 500, 401) then value else 0 end) as total
from ((select name, cr, value from table1 
      ) union all
      (select name, cr, value from table2
      )
     ) t
group by name;
```

In other words, `sum(distinct)` is no longer appropriate when you use `union all`.  In fact, `sum(distinct)` is *never* needed.  At least, I have never found it useful for any queries.

Comment: yes, `distinct` seems suspicious to me as well, however, he has it in the original query ...